# Cannot colour a cell range within a function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to color a cell that is passed as a parameter to a function but it does not seem to work.  Here is the code:

```
Sub my_test(Target As Range)

    With Target.Cells(1, 1).Interior
        .ColorIndex = 3
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

End Sub


Function f_Lookup_domain(P_Cell_name As Range, ByVal P_Default As String) As String

    Call my_test(P_Cell_name)
    v_Cell_name = P_Cell_name.Value

    ' Application.Volatile
    'Lookup the domain of a signal from the cell name
    '
    v_temp = Application.VLookup(v_Cell_name, Range("n_IO_cell_lookup"), 2, False)
    If Application.IsError(v_temp) Then
        ' cell given is not a real IO cell, try to use default
        If P_Default = "CUT" Then
            v_temp = "Unknown"
        Else
            v_temp = P_Default
        End If
    End If
    f_Lookup_domain = v_temp

End Function
```

There is no error report and the function returns the right value. `my_test` is called but the cell is not painted.  If I call `my_test` with the following testbench:

```
Sub Testbench()

    Call my_test(Range("D10"))

End Sub
```

It does colour the cell correctly.  Is as if `P_Cell_name` is not acting like a range?  Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Just in case its relevant - here is how I call the function: =f_Lookup_domain(E17,D16)

Answer (score 1):

A user defined function called like that cannot modify attributes of a range or sheet (except those related to its value), if you try it will silently fail.

[Description of limitations of custom functions in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170787).

[Conditional Formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx) features can help.

Comment: for teh 2nd time in a row we are encountering this today ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I was trying to replace conditional formatting as I now have 4 formats I would like to convey instead of the 3 that I had.  I will have to come up with another way of doing it.